# How to get rid of the tilde in the Spanish version of \inf?

Tags: spanish

I'm using Babel in Spanish and I'm trying to stick to a more latinesque version of `\inf` that **does not** have a tilde.

So far, I have tried using

```
\renewcommand{\inf}{\mathrm{inf}}
```

but it does not seem to be able to override the default version of *ínf*.

Here is a MWE that contains the important parts of my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Tipografiado y preferencias regionales
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes,textcomp,microtype}

% Matemáticas
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Comandos
\renewcommand{\inf}{\mathrm{inf}}

\begin{document}
    \[ \inf \]
\end{document}
```

> Is there anything I can do to override the Spanish version of `\inf` so it **does not** have tilde?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although cfr's answer did the trick and I really appreciate it, I will stick to the broader and more elegant solution of using

```
\unaccentedoperators
```

when working with Babel in Spanish.

Comment: @cfr Based on the time when the question was asked (02:38:13Z) and the time this answer was posted (03:04:45Z), I think the likely thing is that the OP didn't already have this solution, but found it after asking the question. IMO your answer does not need to be deleted either.

Comment: IMO your answer definitely was useful and there was no necessity for deleting it. And yes, I did not know about this solution. I hope you can repost your solution for anyone that wants more... granularity in the future.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Maybe I misunderstood the 'stick to' . I read that as meaning this is how you were doing it before you asked the question. I'm not sure about my answer: I deleted it because this seemed a much better solution (which I wasn't aware of) and I wouldn't have suggested anything else, had I known this was available.